# Relacionamento Tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, modelagem

Tenho uma tabela `Endereco` que serve de tanto para `Funcionario` quanto para Fornecedor:

```
1 Funcionario possui 1 Endereco
1 Fornecedor possui 1 Endereco
```

Como crio este relacionamento sem ter inconsistências?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que é isto que você deseja:

```
CREATE TABLE Fornecedor {
  id INT(4) NOT NULL UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  endereco INT(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (endereco) REFERENCES Endereco(idEndereco)
}

CREATE TABLE Funcionario {
  id INT(4) NOT NULL UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  endereco INT(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (endereco) REFERENCES Endereco(idEndereco)
}

CREATE TABLE Endereco {
  idEndereco INT(4) NOT NULL UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  logradouro VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  cidade VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  estado CHAR(02) NOT NULL,
  cep VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL.
  PRIMARY KEY(idEndereco)
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/Relationship.sql).

É claro que há diversas outras maneiras de fazer isto e organizar melhor um banco de dados por completo. Este é só um exemplo, sem requisitos reais fica difícil fazer algo correto. Evidentemente só coloquei campos de exemplo e não normalizai os demais dados como cidades, por exemplo.

Evidentemente só isto não basta, é possível que seja necessários restrições e gatilhos para "garantir" a consistência. E mesmo isto pode não ser suficiente porque se você restringir demais no banco de dados pode impedir certas tarefas da aplicação.

Como saber o que mais é necessário? Ter requisitos reais, completos, bem fundamentados ajuda bastante. Codifica a solução é a parte fácil, achar os requisitos é que é difícil.

Na verdade pode ser que a modelagem esteja toda errada. Por exemplo, eu provavelmente não separaria o que é fornecedor e funcionário, pelo menos não para o contexto que estou imaginando. Se todo mundo terá apenas um endereço diretamente relacionado 1 para 1, provavelmente eu não separaria em outra tabela. Mas separaria por se o relacionamento for diferente de 1 para 1.

Enfim, posso melhorar a informação da resposta se for melhorada a informação da pergunta.

Comment: Acho que como design a fim de evitar inconsistências, a abordagem poderia deixar um fornecedor e um funcionário partilharem do mesmo endereço. Penso que, ocorrendo isso, poderiam haver edições e exclusões indesejadas.

Comment: Pode ser, mas precisaria de mais dados para ter certeza do que ele quer. Mas tenho minhas dúvidas se deveria ter uma tabela separada neste caso. Ou se tiver que ser separada por qualquer razão, então deveria separar no endereço também. Esses requisitos sem fundamento são complicados, mas ele dando *feedback* eu melhoro. É óbvio que tem como evitar estes problemas citados se for necessário mas chega um ponto que fica tão complicado que é melhor redesenhar toda a modelagem.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, a modelagem proposta traz este risco apenas se a aplicação permitir isto de alguma maneira. É perfeitamente possível Funcionário e Fornecedor utilizarem uma mesma tabela sem haver edições e exclusões indesejadas.

Comment: @Dherik Aí vem uma opinião minha: a melhor segurança de dados está em banco. Enfim, o jeito é esperar o autor da pergunta se manifestar.